# How to disable graphics mode switch at boot

Tags: boot, grub2, graphics

I have a couple of Intel Atom D2550 Cedarview systems with the unsupported PowerVR integrated graphics.

I was able to install Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 without trouble, however when the system boots, after a bunch of normal bootup messages scroll past faster than I can read, there's a graphics mode switch, the monitor goes blank and after a couple seconds goes into standby due to no video input.

The system has completed booting, and I can access it via ssh.

I would like to simply disable that video mode switch and have it boot with a straight text console.

I've tried adding "nomodeset" at the end of the kernel boot line in the grub config, as well as tried changing some of the gfxmode grub variables, but nothing seems to prevent that initial mode switch and resulting blank screen.

Is there an authoritative, reliable way to disable that initial graphics mode switch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show or hide boot messages when Ubuntu starts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts).

Comment: Did you see this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/409343/graphics-problem-with-cedarview-and-log-in-screen?rq=1 seems like it might be a duplicate situation? Can you boot in recovery mode?